# Show specific rows in SQL by not existing in another table

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm not very experienced in advanced SQL and stackoverflow, so I'm trying my best to explain what I need.

Let's say I have a table called 'Shift' and a table called 'Schedule'.

> **'Shift' has columns 'shift_id, shift_start, shift_end, shift_day,
>   shift_function_id'.**
>
> shift_start represents a start time.
>
> shift_end represents a end time.
>
> shift_day represents the number of the day in a week (0-6 starting on
>   sunday).
>
> shift_function_id represents a function_id belonging to the shift.

---

> **'Schedule' has columns 'schedule_id, schedule_date, schedule_start,
>   schedule_end, schedule_function_id'.**
>
> schedule_date represents the date of a schedule.
>
> schedule_start represents start time.
>
> schedule_end represents end time.
>
> schedule_function_id represents a function_id belonging to the
>   schedule.

What I'm trying to do is if a row from 'Shift' doesn't exist in table 'Schedule' with a given specific date `where shift_start = schedule_start AND shift_end = schedule_end AND shift_function_id = schedule_function_id`, then show the row.

Here's an example:

```
SELECT shift_id, shift_day, shift_start, shift_end, function_id, function_name, function_color
FROM Shift
LEFT JOIN Function
ON function_id = shift_function_id
WHERE shift_day = $day
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM Schedule
    WHERE schedule_date = '$date' AND schedule_start = shift_start AND schedule_end = shift_end AND schedule_function_id = shift_function_id
)
ORDER BY function_name, shift_start, shift_end;
```

**The problem is**

If I have 2 shifts with the same starting and end time and table 'Schedule' contains **ONE** row with the same function_id and starting and end time, **BOTH** the 2 shifts won't show up.

Here's an example of the table content:

**Schedule**

```
schedule_id: 310
schedule_date: 2020-01-11
schedule_start: 16:30:00
schedule_end: 20:00:00
schedule_function_id: 27
```

**Shift**

```
shift_id: 45
shift_day: 6
shift_start: 16:30:00
shift_end: 20:00:00
shift_function_id: 27

shift_id: 46
shift_day: 6
shift_start: 16:30:00
shift_end: 20:00:00
shift_function_id: 27
```

**BOTH** 2 rows from 'Shift' dont show up anymore'.

**What I want**

I want if 'Schedule' only has 1 row which contains the same information as the given data in 'Shift', I want the other row to show up.

If 'Schedule' has 2 rows with the same information, none to show up. It just needs to depend on how many rows 'Schedule' has with the same information.

**IMAGES**

**When nothing is filled in, it shows 2 rows with same start and end**

[image]

**When I put a record with same start and end time, it removes both shift rows**

[image]

**I need this, when I only fill in one record with same start and end time**

[image]

Comment: Your perfect requirement is not clear. Please edit your question and post some more sample data and expected result.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've added images. Maybe that makes it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to let `NOT EXISTS` clause remove all rows, Just append 1 row from duplicate rows with MIN (Or MAX) Shift_id -

```
SELECT shift_id, 
       shift_day, 
       shift_start, 
       shift_end, 
       function_id, 
       function_name, 
       function_color 
FROM   shift 
       LEFT JOIN function 
              ON function_id = shift_function_id 
WHERE  shift_day = $day 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                       FROM   schedule 
                       WHERE  schedule_date = '$date' 
                              AND schedule_start = shift_start 
                              AND schedule_end = shift_end 
                              AND schedule_function_id = shift_function_id) 
UNION ALL 
SELECT Min(S1.shift_id), 
       S1.shift_day, 
       S1.shift_start, 
       S1.shift_end, 
       function_id, 
       function_name, 
       function_color 
FROM   shift S1 
       JOIN shift S2 
         ON S1.shift_id <> S2.shift_id 
            AND S1.shift_day = S2.shift_day 
            AND S1.shift_start = S2.shift_start 
            AND S1.shift_end = S2.shift_end 
       LEFT JOIN function 
              ON function_id = S1.shift_function_id 
GROUP  BY S1.shift_day, 
          S1.shift_start, 
          S1.shift_end, 
          function_id, 
          function_name, 
          function_color 
ORDER  BY function_name, 
          shift_start, 
          shift_end;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=341a6150c5ead9421818be393501f53a) is working example.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MariaDB supports window functions, you could use `row_number()` in a subquery to disambiguate records that have the same `(shift_start, shift_end, shift_function)` in the `shift_table`, or the same `(schedule_start, schedule_end, schedule_function)` in the `schedule` table.

You can then use the record rank in the join conditions (I changed the `NOT EXITS` subquery to a `LEFT JOIN` antipattern, but this is essentially the same logic).

```
select s.*, f.*
from (
    select 
        s.*, 
        row_number() over(
            partition by shift_start, shift_end, shift_function 
            order by shift_id
        ) rn
    from shift s
    where shift_day = @shift_day
) s
left join (
    select 
        c.*,
        row_number() over(
            partition by schedule_start, schedule_end, schedule_function 
            order by schedule_id
        ) rn
    from schedule c
    where schedule_date = @schedule_date
) c 
    on  c.schedule_start = s.shift_start 
    and c.schedule_end = s.shift_end
    and c.schedule_function_id = s.shift_function_id
    and c.rn = s.rn
left join function f
    on f.function_id = s.shift_function_id
where c.rn is null
order by f.function_name, s.shift_start, s.shift_end
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is better solution than mine.